# Trouble installing Time::Out Module in Perl

Tags: perl, module, timeout

I'm trying to install [`Time::Out`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Time-Out/Out.pod).

The error looks to be coming from the tar file. Do I need to install anything more? I get the following:

```
install Time::Out
Reading 'C:\Perl\cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 05 Jun 2014 08:53:02 GMT   
Running install for module 'Time::Out'
Checksum for C:\Perl\cpan\sources\authors\id\P\PA\PATL\Time-Out-0.11.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\Perl/cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE

Time-Out-0.11/
Time-Out-0.11/MANIFEST
Time-Out-0.11/t/
Time-Out-0.11/t/01_init.t
Time-Out-0.11/t/pod.t
Time-Out-0.11/t/03_exceptions.t
Time-Out-0.11/t/02_usage.t
Time-Out-0.11/Out.pod
Time-Out-0.11/README
Time-Out-0.11/Out.pm
Time-Out-0.11/META.yml
Time-Out-0.11/Makefile.PL
Time-Out-0.11/Changes
Configuring P/PA/PATL/Time-Out-0.11.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Set up gcc environment - 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Time::Out
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  PATL/Time-Out-0.11.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for P/PA/PATL/Time-Out-0.11.tar.gz
cp Out.pm blib\lib\Time\Out.pm
cp Out.pod blib\lib\Time\Out.pod
  PATL/Time-Out-0.11.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Te
st::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/01_init.t ........ ok
t/02_usage.t .......
The following tests use sleep() so please be patient...
t/02_usage.t ....... 10/15 # Failed test 11 in t/02_usage.t at line 97
#  t/02_usage.t line 97 is: ok($@ eq 'timeout') ;
t/02_usage.t ....... 11/15 # Failed test 12 in t/02_usage.t at line 108
#  t/02_usage.t line 108 is: ok($@ eq 'timeout') ;
# Failed test 13 in t/02_usage.t at line 109  
#  t/02_usage.t line 109 is: ok(!$seen) ;
t/02_usage.t ....... Failed 3/15 subtests
        (less 1 skipped subtest: 11 okay)
t/03_exceptions.t .. ok
t/pod.t ............ skipped: Test::Pod 1.00 required for testing POD

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/02_usage.t     (Wstat: 0 Tests: 15 Failed: 3)
  Failed tests:  11-13
Files=4, Tests=19, 23 wallclock secs ( 0.09 usr +  0.05 sys =  0.14 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/4 test programs. 3/19 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
  PATL/Time-Out-0.11.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\site\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports PATL/Time-Out-0.11.tar.gz
Failed during this command:
 PATL/Time-Out-0.11.tar.gz                    : make_test NO
```

Is there another module I can use similar to the `Time::Out`? Besides `alarm`?

Comment: You don't share any information about your system, but if you look [`cpan testing issues`](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/T/Time-Out.html?oncpan=1&distmat=1&version=0.11&grade=3), you'll see a lot of failures for windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the [Time::Out](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Time-Out/Out.pod) documentation, it does not work for blocking IO on windows. This means - at a minimum - that the tests will fail. You can skip the tests from the cpan shell using `force install Time::Out`, but this may mean that it doesn't work for your purposes.